# How to fix error in ggmap using api requests in mapdist?

Tags: r, ggmap

I have a data frame that contains a list of school districts and schools that are outside of the district that are used. This data frame is not huge but has 4800 rows. Each row contains the town or city, the school and the coordinates. I want to create a new column in my data frame with distance between the town or city and the school in that row. However, I keep running into the same error.

This is the basic for loop that I have tried to run.

```
for (row in 1:nrow(special_ed)){
    z<-mapdist(from = special_ed$Sending.District, to = special_ed$Coords,mode = "driving", source = 'google', api_key = api_secret)
    special_ed <-special_ed%>% mutate(dist = z)
}
```

That produces this error-

```
! Matching was not perfect, returning all.
Error in map():
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `*tmp*`[[c(1, 1)]]:
! no such index at level 1
```

Is that due to the high number of api requests that bypasses the limit for google maps?

Comment: provide data! e.g. `dput(head(your_df))`. Calculation should be simple if coordinates exist. Probably a for-loop is not necessary. `your_df$distance <- distance_function(...)` could be enough.

Comment: R is a vectorized language thus you are sending the entire column of values using the syntax: `special_ed$Sending.District`.  To loop through individual rows use the subscript notation `[row]` like this: `special_ed[row]$Sending.District`.  Also, you may want to print out z, to help debug which inputs values are generating the error.